# Can't revert SUPEE-9767 v1

Tags: upgrade, patches, supee-9767, magento-1.9.3.4

I want to upgrade my Magento version 1.9.3.3 to 1.9.3.4. As I understand it I have to revert SUPEE-9767 v1 using the command `sh PATCH-SUPEE-9767.sh -R`.

When I run this command I get the following error log from it:

```
sh PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.9.3.2_v1-2017-05-25-09-03-28.sh -R
PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.9.3.2_v1-2017-05-25-09-03-28.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.9.3.2_v1-2017-05-25-09-03-28.sh: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.9.3.2_v1-2017-05-25-09-03-28.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.9.3.2_v1-2017-05-25-09-03-28.sh: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.9.3.2_v1-2017-05-25-09-03-28.sh: 25: PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.9.3.2_v1-2017-05-25-09-03-28.sh: 0: not found
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
-e ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Checkout/Formkey.php
Unreversed patch detected!  Ignore -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Notification/Symlink.php
Unreversed patch detected!  Ignore -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Filter/Date.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Config/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/GalleryController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/system.xml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 232.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Adapter/Zend/Cache.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Container/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Xml/Excel.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Uploader.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Model/Widget/Instance.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Helper/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/Adminhtml/MobileController.php
Unreversed patch detected!  Ignore -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/formkey.phtml
Unreversed patch detected!  Ignore -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/symlink.phtml
Unreversed patch detected!  Ignore -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/head.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
checking file app/etc/config.xml
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
Unreversed patch detected!  Ignore -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Core.csv
Unreversed patch detected!  Ignore -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Dataflow.csv
Unreversed patch detected!  Ignore -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_XmlConnect.csv
Unreversed patch detected!  Ignore -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file downloader/Maged/Connect.php
checking file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
checking file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
checking file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.js
checking file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js
checking file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.map
checking file js/varien/payment.js
checking file skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js
```

So unfortunately I'm not able to revert this, so I can't upgrade to 1.9.3.4. Does anyone have a clue about what is going on?

Comment: are you sure v1 of the patch was installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are get Unreversed patch detected! errors because original v1 patch did not install successfully. In other words, whenever you see a message "Unreversed patch detected!", V1 patch didn't not make any changes to those files when you installed it originally. It skipped them probably.

For you to be able to reverse V1, you have to open the V1 patch with an EDITOR and remove **patches code** for the files that you see show "Unreversed patch detected!"
**I counted the following from the list provided:**

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Checkout/Formkey.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Notification/Symlink.php
app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/Adminhtml/MobileController.php
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/formkey.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/symlink.phtml
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Core.csv
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Dataflow.csv
app/locale/en_US/Mage_XmlConnect.csv
```

---

You also have HUNK failed at 232

```
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/system.xml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 232.
```

You could possibly modified this file manually after V1 installation, compare this file with original Magento system.xml file for your version. There must be something missing in the code.

Comment: It was indeed a problem with the v1 patch not installing succesfully. I ended up repatching v1, then reverting v1. After this I was able to install patch v2. Thanks for your help!